# How can I search values in pandas dataframe that could be in more than one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have a DataFrame like that:

```
index A B C
0     1 0 2
1     0 0 3
2     0 1 5
3     0 2 1
4     1 2 2
5     0 2 5
```

And I need to get only the rows that contains number 1,
but the number 1 can be in any column in df.

Ex:

```
index A B C
0     1 0 2
2     0 1 5
3     0 2 1
4     1 2 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Check

```
df = df[df.eq(1).any(axis=1)]
```